# CSS en select Contact Form 7

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

Tengo un problema que me esta matando con el Contact Form 7 de Wordpress y con el tema del estilo del select. Explico:

Tengo dos selects con diseño de bootstrap y se muestran así:

[image: visual]

Como veís, el addon con el icono se muestra más grande que el select en sí, lo cual descuadra el formulario completo.

He probado con css mil maneras para que el tamaño sea el mismo pero no funciona nada. He encontrado el problema y reside en el atributo que pone Contact form 7 "wpcf7-form-control-wrap fechacamp" que provoca que haya ese hueco arriba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabría que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Datos técnicos:

Contact form 7 versión 5.0.1
Wordpress versión 4.9.5

Código html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                           <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  [select* anocamp id:anocamp class:form-control class:selectpicker "Seleccione el año del campamento"]
                                     </div>
                           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
 [select* fechacamp id:fechacamp class:form-control class:selectpicker "Seleccione la fecha del campamento"]
                                    </div>
                           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

El css del wpcf7-form-control-wrap es así de simple, el css de lo demás es css básico de bootstrap.

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Tambien deberias colocar el css de los dos elementos en cuestion.

Comment: @alanfcm el css es de bootstrap editando colores. Lo he revisado de arriba abajo y no es ningún error en el css, incluso quitandole todo el css sigue dando el mismo error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres hacer la altura igual, haz el css como sigue:

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .input-group {
    display:flex;
}
```